# I want to put a navigation bar in center using css

Tags: css

Following is the link of a web page.
https://pbx.wave-tel.com/register
It has a navigation bar containing verification, your details and hosting contrex.
I want to set this bar in the center of the page without using margin or padding as it disturbs the responsive display. I can only change the CSS as i do not have access to HTML, Please help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.swMain ul.anchor li {
display:inline-block;
float:none;
}

.swMain #navSummary {
text-align:center;
}
```

Try this then, I have edited for your requirement!!

Comment: I cannot create a new div as i donot have its html plus using width or margin is disturbs the responsive display. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do this changes

CSS

```
.swMain ul.anchor li a {
text-align: center;
margin-top: -15px;
padding-top: 0;
}
.swMain ul.anchor li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}
.swMain #navSummary {
text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your css

```
.widget-menu-widget{
    padding-left : 50%;
    margin-left : -323px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
 .swMain #navSummary {
   text-align-center;
 }     
 .swMain ul.anchor li {
   /*float: left;*/ remove float left
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .swMain ul.anchor li a {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .nav-tabs>li {
   /*float: left;*/ remove float left
 }
```

Note: you need to add these to your existing styles